# c3.js zoom extent isn't working as expected

Tags: charts, zooming, data-visualization, c3.js, extent

I'm using C3.js and want to limit the zoom-level in a line-chart, so the user won't be able to zoom-in infinitely.

I can't get this done at all. No matter what I do, the `extent` in 
`zoom: { enabled: true, extent: [1, 5] }` doesn't change anything.

I've created an example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/toxy1337/pen/GdgOQq?editors=0010)

I'm aware this is, according to the [documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#zoom-extent), an experimental feature, but could someone help me with it (if I'm doing something wrong) or tell me that this is a bug/unfinished feature implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right,

```
 zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    extent: [1, 5],
 },
```

seems to be correct config.

Could you **try a different version**?

For example, it seems to be working with c3 **v0.4.10** - 
[see this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/en91nL2e/2/).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized by myself, as I'd already recognized some other differences between 0.4.x and 0.5.x versions (like this: [Tooltip failing](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/2154#issuecomment-382699963))